# What is the maximum radius for the geocode parameter in the twitter search API?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-search

Hello I am fetching recent tweets using twitter search api and want to know maximum radius limit for geocode parameter

```
search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=22.7195687,75.8577258,1km&result_type=recent
```

presently I am using 1 km